# Extracting data from xbrl with xpath2

Tags: xbrl

Please help me xbrl:

```
<us-gaap:Assets contextRef="FI2012Q4_us-gaap_StatementBusinessSegmentsAxis_aap_AiMember" decimals="-3" id="Fact-A33F4BA6A286071BBC9DA51D8C4DE584" unitRef="usd">261128000</us-gaap:Assets>
```

I am extracting the value from xbrl (sec.us) Assets :261128000 by using following code, but I want to be more specific, I only want to print

> Asset :261128000 when contextRef="FI2012Q4"

or

> Asset:5564774000 when the  contextRef="FI2013Q4"

How I can add condition while printing the value in the following code?

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query("/xbrli:xbrl/us-gaap:AccountsPayableCurrent[@unitRef='usd']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Select assets for Q4/2012:

```
$assets2012Q4 = $xpath->query("/xbrli:xbrl/us-gaap:Assets[@unitRef='usd'][@contextRef='FI2012Q4']");
```

Please, be aware that you are building a custom solution for a specific XBRL instance document here. For a different XBRL instance it won't work. If you are trying to build a generic XBRL solution with XPath alone, I can only strongly discourage you to do this. XBRL adds a lot more semantics to XML than XPath can handle.

Comment: Thank you very much,Dennis knochenwefel,i am really grateful to you.

Comment: I am trying to build a generic XBRL solution,not for a specific XBRL document,what will be your suggestion if i want a generic solution.